# Optaplanner - soft scoring rule not working as expected

Tags: optaplanner

I built an application which implements a similar function as task assignment. I thought it works well until recently I noticed the solutions are not optimal. In details, there is a score table for each possible pair between machines and tasks, and usually the number of machines is much less than the number of tasks. I used hard/medium/soft rules, where the soft rule is incremental based on the score of each assignment from the score table.

However, when I reviewed the results after 1-2 hours run, I found out of the unassigned tasks there are many better choices (would achieve higher soft score if assigned) than current assignments. The benchmark reports indicate that the total soft score reached plateau within a hour and then stuck at that score level.

I checked the logic of rules - if the soft rule working perfectly, it should eventually find a way of allocation which achieves the highest overall soft score, whereas meeting the other hard/medium rules, isn't it?

I've been trying various things such as tuning algorithm parameters, scaling the score table, etc. but none delivers the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you might be facing a **score trap** (see docs). In that case, make your constraint score more fine grained to deal with that.

If that's not the case, and you're stuck in a local optima, then I wouldn't play too much with the algorithm parameters - they will probably fix it, but you'll be *overfitting* on that dataset.

Instead, figure out the smallest possible move that gets you of that local optima and a step closer to the global optimum. Add that kind of moves as a **custom move**. For example if a normal swap move can't help, but you see a way of getting there by doing a 3-swap move, then implement that move.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, thanks for your feedback. In my case each task could be assigned to one machine or not assigned at all, and each assignment has a score. So I don't have the need of moving multiple tasks at once as each task is independent. The current moves are either SwapMove (swap two tasks) or ChangeMoves (change a machine to assign). Those are already smallest possible moves - aren't they? I didn't specify a list of custom moves but only implemented move filters, due to the large size of data custom moves will have a strong impact on performance.

Comment: Alternatively, if there is a way to sort the candidate list of tasks each time to make sure it always picks the possible task of the highest score, that would probably do. But this would involve reading the score table every time and possibly slows down things a lot, and I am not sure how to implement it as custom moves.

Comment: I don't think doing a 3-swap move will help, if it just randomly choose 3 tasks to swap. The issue is among the unassigned tasks, there are better candidates not picked yet but very hard to hit them out of a large pool.

Comment: Is there a way that I can sort the entity list by its score (which will add up to total soft score) every time to make sure the planner always select the best candidate in a 'greedy' manner?

Comment: *Try Tabu Search*  - by default it will use an acceptedSelectionCount of 1000 with random JUST_IN_TIME selection. If you really want to try all moves at every step, *use VARIABLE_NEIGHBERHOOD_DESCENT* - that does exactly what you want: select all moves in original order (no JIT selection). Great for small problems, terrible for medium/big.

Comment: My current algorithm uses a combined CH + Simulated Annealing + Tabu, with tuned parameters. I've tried using default Tabu with JIT move selector, but it's not performing as well as my tuned algorithms. The moves are already at the finest granularity (both change move and swap move) and I am not sure what other custom moves it could be.

Comment: The way I evaluate the results is, on top of the total soft score, I also check # of unassigned tasks for each machine for every result, ideally the numbers should be close to 0, but the reality is for each machine there are bunches of unassigned tasks that having higher scores than the assigned task of the lowest score of each machine.

Comment: I'd give Variable Neighborhood Descent a try, but usually the problems I am trying to solve are large, so the scalability is the key. And I doubt as VND selects the first improving move - a task A could improve total score slightly when assigned to Machine B, but there is another task C could further increase the score when allocated to B but comes later.